# Function returns a Function

Tags: c++, templates, generics

How am I returning another function? The compiler error I get (on Visual Studio) is "function returns function"

```
template <>
class encoder<uint16_t, endian_swap> {
public:
    uint16_t opeartor () (uint16_t& value){
        // do something
    }
};
```

Comment: You wrote `opeartor` instead of `operator`. Are you showing the real code?

Comment: No worries, that happens ;)

Comment: My God - I did the same thing... I had `opeerator()`, and only after an hour of trying to understand what I was doing wrong did I stumble on this answer... just a %^*^ typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because

```
uint16_t opeartor ()
```

looks like a declaration of a function called `opeartor` which takes no arguments and returns `uint16_t`. Try

```
uint16_t operator ()
```